# how can I convert the for-while loop into a for-for loop and achieve the same output?

Tags: python, loops, type-conversion, nested-loops

This code successfully prints a youtube play button

```
rows = 6
symbol = '\U0001f34a'

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print('{'+symbol+'}', end = '')
    print()

for x in range(rows):   
    while x < 5:
        print('{'+symbol+'}', end = '')
        x+=1

    print()
```

I tried to change the while loop into a for loop and print a "upside-down" right triangle. but it doesnt work.

```
rows = 6
symbol = '\U0001f34a'

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print('{'+symbol+'}', end = '')
    print()

for x in range(rows):   
    for x in range(5):
        print('{'+symbol+'}', end = '')

    print()
```

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem, or add details if you are looking for something else or clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop is always in `range(5)` so it will not print the desired output.

Firstly, you can use your 1st loop to set up the second, but it will be the same as above, and wont make a descending order. In order to do that, I reversed the 1st range :

```
for x in range(rows)[::-1]:  # Reverse the range
    for y in range(x):       # Use 1st loop variable as parameter
        print('{'+symbol+'}', end = '')
```

Output, with a `'O'` since I didnt set up the encoding for your symbol

```
{O}
{O}{O}
{O}{O}{O}
{O}{O}{O}{O}
{O}{O}{O}{O}{O}
{O}{O}{O}{O}{O}{O}
{O}{O}{O}{O}{O}
{O}{O}{O}{O}
{O}{O}{O}
{O}{O}
{O}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok thanks for the help guys I see where I messed up.when i was converting the while loop to a for loop I was supposed to find the range in the iteration of the outer for loop. Here is my new code that works perfectly

```
rows = 6
symbol = '\U0001f34a'

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print('{'+symbol+'}', end = '')
    print()

for x in range(rows,0,-1):   
    for e in range(x,1,-1):
        print('{'+symbol+'}', end = '')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

It was fun to create, so here is my code that works.
The second for loop start to max length and end at 0 with a step of -1, with this you can create a for loop that decreases

```py
    for i in range(rows):
        print('{'+symbol+'}'*(i+1))
    for i in range(rows,0,-1):
        print('{'+symbol+'}'*(i-1))
```